# How to get cells to follow the head in snake game

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, indexing

Im building a simple snake game in javascript and need help with making the snake body follow the head. Im working on a 20x20 grid where each cell has a number.
The snake head is at index 0 in my variable, the following indexes are the snake body. Cells are  placed in an array. Of course when i have the snake going 'up', all the snake cells simply move up one cell. Any ideas how to make logic that would make the snake body follow the head which is at index 0 in my variable. I basically need every index past 0 in my snake variable to go into the cell of the one in front of it every time the loop runs. Any ideas?

[image: the snake]

```
const cells = []

let snake = [120, 121, 122]

let direction = 'up'


    if (direction === 'right') {
      for (var i = snake.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        cells[snake[i]].classList.remove('snake')
        snake[i] += 1
        cells[snake[i]].classList.add('snake')

      }
    } else if (direction === 'up') {
      for (var i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {

        cells[snake[i]].classList.remove('snake')
        snake[i] -= width
        cells[snake[i]].classList.add('snake')
        console.log(snake[i])

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Of course when i have the snake going 'up', all the snake cells simply move up one cell.

This is actually not true. It's not *all* the cells that go up. It's just the tail that becomes the head.

You need to just pop your tail out of your snake's array and prepend it as a head, relative to the previous head.